# awk: send results to file named using bash variable

Tags: bash, file, variables, awk, send

I have a bash variable `LOG_FILENAME` which stores the name of a log file. What I want to 
do is to launch `iostat -xnmp` and get fields 9, 10 and 11 of every record of every its iteration matching pattern stored in bash variable `DEVICE`. Number of iterations is stored in `time` bash var. What I was trying to do is:

```
iostat -xnmp 5 $time | awk -v log=$LOG_FILENAME "/$DEVICE/" '{print $9" "$10" "$11}' input >> $log
```

and lots of variations with `ENVIRON` and others...but still couldn't figure out where I am wrong. I am getting a syntax error most of the time. There are no particular requirements yet, so any solution is suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this (one liners are okay but it is easier to humans to read as separate lines):

```
iostat -xnmp  $time | 
awk -v dev=$DEVICE  'index($0,dev)>0 {print $9,$10,$11}' >> $log
```

you read from stdin.  `index($0,dev)>0` was used because I think you have one disk device in mind.  `index($0,dev)>0` can be shortened to `index($0,dev)`  with less clarity for folks learning awk.

Comment: This causes syntax error message too. I've modified it to look like this:
iostat -xnmp 5 $time | awk -v dev=$DEVICE -v log=$LOG_FILENAME 'index($0,dev)>0 {print $9,$10,$11}' >> $log, but that causes an ambiguous redirect error for variable $log.

Comment: My bad - lose the "5" before $time.  As a general comment, these kinds of questions are hard to answer.  You will get better answers by showing your script and your desired output.

Comment: Well, the script isn't really interesting. $DEVICE var is filled manually, so as the $time (it is a script parameters). $LOG_FILENAME stores the date and device name in one string. That's all...
I want the user to start script like this (for example): script 5 c0t2d0 and I need it to generate info into file with timestamps. At first I made it to work by another way (without making iostat to do iterations), but that gives only average disk usage information, so I need to pass parameters directly to iostat and send them to a file.

Comment: You've GOT to quote your shell variables, e.g. `"$time"`, not `$time`. Always quote all shell variables unless you have a very specific reason not to and know exactly what you're doing, otherwise you will get bitten now or in future by cryptic, unexpected results (google it).

Comment: Made that, but still getting a new file with strange name every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If DEVICE is well formed (eg, does not contain a `/`), either of these should work:

```
... | awk  "/$DEVICE/"'{print $9, $10, $11}' OFS=' ' >> $LOG_FILENAME
```

(Note: you cannot have any space between the `'` and the `"`)
or

```
... | awk 'match($0, device) {print $9, $10, $11 >> log}' OFS=' ' \
            device="$DEVICE" log=$LOG_FILENAME
```

Comment: I did not see where "input" was defined at all - awk reads stdin.

Comment: OK, the first one works :)
But what I'm interested in: the file size increases only when all iostat iterations are finished. So, if I break the execution nothing gets to a file. And there is another issue worrying me: will this work if I tell iostat to make really a lot of iterations? I need it to run for 3-7 days.

Comment: Use the second version and add `close log` after the print command to flush the output.

Comment: I get the syntax error when I use the second version while the first one works.
The OS is Solaris 10, but I can't figure out the version of awk (--v, --version and --help doesn't work). If that means something...

Comment: What is the error you get?  `a syntax error` is not particularly descriptive.

Comment: The awk string now looks like this: `iostat -xnmp 5 $time | awk 'match($0, device) {print $9, $10, $11 >> log}' OFS=' ' device="$DEVICE" log=$LOG_FILENAME`. And I get this: `awk: syntax error near line 1` and this: `awk: bailing out near line 1`. That really doesn't tell a lot :(

Comment: It tells you everything you need to know: You are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk and /usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Never do that. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk. By the way, don't do the first version above as it exposes you to shell quoting issues. You also might want to add a "^" and "$" to the device name to anchor it, and watch out for RE metacharacters like ".".

Comment: I made a checking procedure before, so user couldn't enter a non-existing device. It checks existence of what is strictly typed in :)
The nawk works, but it creates numerous files instead of writing to a single log file. It looks like this now: `iostat -xnmp 5 $time | nawk 'match($0, device) {print $9, $10, $11 >> log; close log}' OFS=' ' device="$DEVICE" log=$LOG_FILENAME`

Comment: A few things: It is not possible for the script in your comment to create multiple files so there must be something you're not showing us. Get back to using the "-v" variable setting style for clarity and to avoid future surprises. Instead of `awk -v log="file" '{ print > log }'`, it makes more sense to do `awk '{ print }' > file`. And again - quote your shell variables.